# NuGet: Find and delete code using Powershell / uninstall.ps1

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package, envdte

I have a few NuGet packages that I've put together, with one of them being a common project referenced by all the others.

This common project inserts a configuration class into the `App_Start` folder, and a method on this class is then invoked by WebActivator.

For one of the other packages I wish to add one more line of code to this method and I achieve this using *install.ps1* (using code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983749/nuget-possibility-of-adding-a-line-of-code-via-powershell)).

To be a diligent NuGet package developer, I should probably remove this line of code if the NuGet package is uninstalled.

To do this removal I've tried using the [FindPattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.editpoint.findpattern.aspx) method of the FileCodeModel to find the line of code, but haven't had any luck in getting it to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
$app_start = $project.ProjectItems.Item("App_Start")
$item = $app_start.ProjectItems.Item("my-config-file.cs")
$namespace = $item.FileCodeModel.CodeElements | ? {$_.Kind -eq 5}
$class = $namespace.Members.Item("My-Config-Class")
$method = $class.Members.Item("My-Method-Name")
$startPoint = $method.GetStartPoint([EnvDTE.vsCMPart]::vsCMPartBody)
$startPoint = $startPoint.CreateEditPoint()
$endPoint = $method.GetEndpoint([EnvDTE.vsCMPart]::vsCMPartBody)
$endPoint = $endpoint.CreateEditPoint()     
$startPoint.FindPattern("known-line-of-code", [EnvDTE.vsCMPart]::vsFindOptionsFromStart, ref $endPoint)
```

Specifically, it's that last line, `FindPattern`, that I'm having trouble with. The docs list another optional parameter, and judging by Visual Studio's exception message...

> Exception calling "FindPattern" with "3" argument(s): "Type mismatch.

...I guess I'm supposed to supply this parameter. But what do I supply it with?

And even if I *could* find the line of code, how do I then delete it?

Or is `FindPattern` the wrong way to proceed? Is there another way to remove a known line of code?

Comment: `(int) ([EnvDTE.vsCMPart]::vsFindOptionsFromStart)` Is that supposed to be a cast? `[int]([EnvDTE.vsCMPart]::vsFindOptionsFromStart)` is what that should be assuming `[EnvDTE.vsCMPart]::vsFindOptionsFromStart` on its own is not viable. Is this something similar? `ref $endPoint` should be `[ref]$endPoint` maybe? FYI I know nothing about NuGet

Comment: My apologies, @Matt - that `(int)` shouldn't have been posted in the question - it was lingering from a trial-and-error period. It shouldn't be there, and even if I add parentheses that still makes no difference. I'll edit the question to reflect how I believe it should be entered. [If included, Visual Studio highlights the cast as an exception.]